# Adding event listeners to current and future elements with a particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With JQuery, is it possible to add an event listener to any element that currently, **or will in the future**, have a particular class?

I'm working on a project that makes heavy use of contentEditable, so the DOM is changing, and elements can have classes added and removed as a result of user input.

I would like to be able to say "elements of class X should do Y when clicked", but if I understand correctly, $(".X").click(Y) will only add the event listener to elements that currently have class X.

Furthermore, if an element is no-longer part of class X, then it will still have the click event listener.

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at `on` method http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yep. What you're talking about is called event delegation. Here's an example:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.innerElement', function(){
   /// Do stuff
});
```

In your case, `#container` would be an element that is known to exist on page load which will contain the child elements you care about (either now or in the future). This approach takes advantage of event bubbling in the DOM.

As another poster mentioned, the live method will also work -- but it has been deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and is generally not as performant as using more selective delegation (such as the example above).

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the clear explanation above... the jQuery API site REALLY needs to clean up their explanations for some things. Unclear example code and vague explanations can only get you so far.

Comment: can you tell how to do the same in JavaScript only?

Comment: @SHANK, if you need this, I'd say you need jQuery. Implementing event delegation yourself would probably be pretty tough. If you're hell-bent on trying, you basically need to look at the event target and try to see if it matches a CSS selector. That's not trivial, though.

Comment: what if you need `event.target` in the listener? For instance, if I click on an element X that's inside `.innerElement`, the event will be dispatched (as expected) but `event.target` will be `#container` (while `event.currentTarget` will be the element X.

Answer (score 5):

you'll want to use event delegation.  jquery 1.7 has made this more abstract than previous versions, but it looks something like this:

```
$("#myWrappingElement").on("click", ".myclass", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

this basically adds a click event listener to the #myWrappingElement element, and jquery will automagically look to see what the original event target was and fire the proper function.  this means you can add or remove .myclass elements and still have events fire on them.

Comment: I assume that #myWrappingElement could be a class rather than an id?

Comment: can it be the document?

Comment: @light24bulbs, yes, it can be.  a lot of listeners at the document level _could_ indicate poor design though, so watch out.

Answer (score -1):

the jQuery live() method swill allow to have a "live" action listener - so if new DOM elements match the selector, they will be attached to the action listener. For example:

```
$(".X").live("click", function(){
    alert('some action');
});
```

See the documentation here for more info: http://api.jquery.com/live/

I'm not sure that the second part of your question about keeping the action listener attached after removing the class os possible - someone else might have a solution though.

Comment: That's the first I ever heard that `.live()` never worked very well.  `.delegate()`, `.live()` and `.bind()` have been unified in jQuery 1.7+ with `.on()` so one should switch to `.on()` when convenient if moving to jQuery 1.7+, but there are likely zillions of pages using `.live()` quite fine.

Comment: @nathangonzalez "never really worked very well". It was and still **is** working as advertised. It is somewhat wasteful, working just fine.

Comment: @jfriend00, `.live()` has been deprecated, not integrated with `.on()`.  if you'll actually read the documentation being linked to you'll see the myriad drawbacks and issues with using `live()`.

Comment: Apologies, I haven't looked at the changes in 1.7.

Comment: @nathangonzalez - `.on()` is a superset of `.live()` meant as a replacement.  Yes, I know it's been deprecated.  That means you should  be moving away from it and not write new code using it (if you're using jQuery 1.7+).  It doesn't mean it's busted or stopped working.  And, I find it annoying that so many people immediately downvote anyone who suggests `.live()`.  Most of the world isn't even yet using jQuery 1.7.  A comment about `.live()` being deprecated in JQuery 1.7+ and suggesting .on() instead would be fine.

Comment: @jfriend00, copied straight from the jquery api doc on `.live()`: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."  i'd say that means don't ever use `.live()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 `.live` was always busted, it's a useless method with no purpose. Even back before 1.7 it should never be used. `.delegate` was always the better solution.

Comment: Yes, there are better ways of doing it by scoping to a closer parent than the document object, but `.live()` was not useless or busted.  It's working fine in zillions of web pages.  I agree with the recommendation to use a more efficient way (depending upon jQuery version), but you guys calling `.live()` useless or didn't work well is going overboard.  If I had a bunch of working web pages using `.live()`, I would find no reason to immediately interrupt my new feature development and change them to `.live()`.  If I was moving to jQuery 1.7, I would migrate to `.on()` when it was convenient.