# how to attach hover handler to TD elements, filtering on a class selector that may be applied in the future

Tags: jquery, jquery-on, jquery-delegate

My table will have a number of TD elements that get assigned a class, `.foo`, during the course of the user working with the data. The table might have a few hundred cells and only a dozen of those may acquire the `.foo` class.  I want to listen for `hover` on those particular TD elements. It looks as though the delegate() method in jQuery listens for *javascript* events, whereas `hover` is a *jQuery* event, is that right?  How to create a delegate to listen for `hover` on `TD.foo` elements that will have the `.foo` class assigned to them in the *future*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding event listeners to current and future elements with a particular class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459204/adding-event-listeners-to-current-and-future-elements-with-a-particular-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is not recommended for use in newer jQuery, you should use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> > As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

```
$('#table').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'td.foo', function(e) {
    if(e.type === 'mouseenter') {
        //hover in
    } else {
        //hover out
    }
});
```

Comment: Come on, it's not even deprecated :).

Comment: My bad, it's not deprecated but not the recommended way anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tblId").on("hover", ".foo", function() {
  // Code here
});
```

Comment: `on("hover"` was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9, so you should either use `on("mouseenter mouseleave"` (like @OneOfOne), or `.hover()` :)

Comment: Gah, really?  Good to know!

Comment: I started learning jQuery 2 years ago and recently upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9.  EVERYTHING broke! lol