# totaling dynamically created inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following can add or remove a table using click events. In the top there is a table that is not dynamically created that I have an input field called name="total_hrs" that I would like to total all the hours entered into each of the inputs name="hours' + i + '"

The current function hrsUpdate only gives me the last inputs entered value. How can that function be modified to total all of the hours inputs and reduce in value if a table is removed?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
var i = 1;

function addrow() {
    $('#mytable').before('<table><tr><td><input id="fname' + i + '" name="fname' + i + '" type="text" value=""></input></td><td><input id="lname' + i + '" name="lname' + i + '" type="text" value=""></input></td><td><input id="email' + i + '" name="email' + i + '" type="text" value=""></input></td><td><input id="hours' + i + '" name="hours' + i + '" type="text" value="" onchange="hrsUpdate(this.value)"></input></td><td><a class="remove" id="' + i + '" href="#">Remove</a></td></tr></table>');
    i++;
}

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).parents('table').remove();
});

function hrsUpdate(hrs) {
    var hours = hrs;
    alert(hours);
    document.getElementById('total_hrs').value = (hours);
}


</script>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value=""></input>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value=""></input>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value=""></input>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="total_hrs" name="total_hrs" type="text" value=""></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="mytable"></table>
        <a href="#" onclick="addrow()"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/f/6/1/11949856271997454136tasto_2_architetto_franc_01.svg.med.png" height="36" width="36" /></a>
</body>
```

edit:

```
<script>
var i = 1;

function addrow() {
    $('#mytable').before('<table><tr><td><input id="fname' + i + '" name="fname' + i + '" type="text" value=""></input></td><td><input id="lname' + i + '" name="lname' + i + '" type="text" value=""></input></td><td><input id="email' + i + '" name="email' + i + '" type="text" value=""></input></td><td><input class = "hours" id="hours' + i + '" name="hours' + i + '" type="text" value="" onchange="hrsUpdate()"></input></td><td><a class="remove" id="' + i + '" href="#">Remove</a></td></tr></table>');
    i++;
}

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).parents('table').remove();
    hrsUpdate();
});


function hrsUpdate() {
    var total_hours = 0;
    $('.hours').each(function(i, elem) {
     total_hours += parseFloat($(elem).val());
  });
  document.getElementById('total_hrs').value = (total_hours);   
}

</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the user can add or remove a row using click events? Your description would indicate that they are adding an entirely new table. Is there a reason that would are using multiple tables, instead of a single table with multiple rows (for entering hours)?

Comment: I appreciate the response back. Yes the user will be able to add or delete a table. The project is in the early stages. Each table will evently house 25 or so elements each driven by a mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your could consider trying the following structure:

```
<span id="total_hours">0.00</span>
<table id="hour_records"></table>
<button id="add_row_btn">Add Row</button>
```

and generate table rows that look like the following:

```
<tr>
    <!-- You could also consider using a default value for the input -->
    <td><input type="text" value="" class="hours_entry"></td>
    <td><button class="remove_row_btn">Remove</button></td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var handleAddRow = function(e) {
        var row = $('<tr></tr>');
        var input = $('<td></td').append('<input type="text" value="" class="hours_entry">');
            input.appendTo(row);
        var remove = $('<td></td').append('<button class="remove_row_btn">Remove</button>');
            remove.appendTo(row);
        row.appendTo('#hour_records');
    };

    var handleRemoveRow = function(e) {
        //Determine the respective row ('<tr>') object and remove it
        $(e.currentTarget).parent().parent().remove();
    };

    var updateTotalHours = function(e) {
        //Assuming that you properly validate all hour entries as numbers
        var total_hours = 0;
        $('.hours_entry').each(function(i, elem) {
            var hours = parseFloat($(elem).val());
            if(!isNaN(hours)) {
                   total_hours += parseFloat($(elem).val());
            }
        });
        $('#total_hours').text(total_hours);
    };

    //Setup the 'add row' event listener
    $('#add_row_btn').on('click', handleAddRow);
    //Setup the 'remove row' event listener
    $('#hour_records').on('click', 'button.remove_row_btn', handleRemoveRow);
    //Setup a listener to update the total hours count
    $('#hour_records').on('change', updateTotalHours);

});
```

Here is a jsFiddle demo that includes some very basic input validation: http://jsfiddle.net/F2hxH/10/

Comment: The concept behind the project is each table will be for a single item for a contractors bid form. When they select an item for a drop down it will fill some of the input boxes with data ftom the mysql database...

Comment: If a custom chages their mind a simple remove or add table will handle the needs...like i said this is in the infancy stages of the concept though.

Comment: I tried your example. It would create 3 input boxes that had a remove option for each and an add row button. When I clicked on any one of the initial three remove buttons...everything would disappear.  When I click to add another row the newly created row remove button did not work and the math was not working.  With all that said you gave me an idea that I got to work. I changed my script to the following...see above edit:

Comment: Hopefully I've addressed most of those issues in my edits. As it turns out, jQuery's $.on() does not attach listeners to elements that match the selector but are added to the DOM after the code executes. Because these table rows are added dynamically, you'd have to attach the listener to a container that is present in the DOM on page load (the 'bound element'), and provide a descendant selector which causes only events that occur on that element to trigger the listener (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459204/adding-event-listeners-to-current-and-future-elements-with-a-particular-class)

Comment: Nice example (fiddle).